# Can we use CNN to effectively learn from a table whose various rows are permuted in the testing dataset, output for each remains same?

Tags: python, deep-learning, permutation, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters

I have a set of classes, 37 to be precise. Each class is represented by a `feature vector of size [1,10]`.
A single input sample has the dimensions of `[6,10]`, where each row in this sample represents a different class.
Input only has one arrangement of these rows, whereas during testing, the rows can be permuted in input sample and output should remain same.
**Can I use CNN to drop the need of training on every permutation by using a kernel of size `[1,10]` which will effectively run slide vertically on input sample?**
The size of the training dataset is considerably less(500 samples). @FilippoGrazioli